# Cordova reports ANDROID_HOME is not set even though it is

Tags: linux, android

I am trying to build the hello world app that comes with Cordova. I created the project and have added the following to my .bashrc:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Android/Sdk/tools:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

When I run echo $ANDROID_HOME, I see the correct path and running echo $PATH also returns the path with the correct sdk path appended. However, when I run sudo cordova build, it still says that $ANDROID_HOME is not set and android is not in your path. I have been trying to fix this for the last 3 hours with no solution :( Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed my problem.

I am not 100% what it was, but it is likely that it had something to do with a combination of `sudo` and my `JAVA_HOME` variable not being set.

I was previously running `sudo cordova build` which was returning the error. I tried deleting and recreating the project after I read somewhere that it might be because of the sudo. After recreating the project, I ran it with just `cordova build` and I got a new error: `Unable to run java -version`. I figured that it was having some trouble locating my jdk installation and I had read somewhere that you needed to assign the JAVA_HOME variable in your .bashrc. So I added in `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_45` and then added `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to my path. After this, it built successfully.